# Azure datafactory - trigger window tumbling blocked

Tags: azure-data-factory

Question
Sign in to vote
0
Sign in to vote
Hi

1. I defined a trigger type Tumbling Window with a "depends on"
2. I Ran the trigger for some time then I had to change
3. I stopped and deleted the dependencies
4. Start again the trigger
5. The trigger on the monitor list blocked on waiting for "depends On"

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Please post more details or some screenshots.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure Data Factory - Trigger Tumbling Window not finish - blocked on "depends On"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58048929/azure-data-factory-trigger-tumbling-window-not-finish-blocked-on-depends-on)